# sqlite python executemany REPLACE IF column meets conidtion ELSE IGNORE

Tags: python, sqlite, replace

I'm currently working on a simple shopping list which is updated from multiple users. The following code does already most of what it needs to do.

User 1 sends queryList one to the database, where the integer 1 stands for an item that has been crossed off but not deleted:

User 2 sends queryList2, where Raspberries have been crossed off and Spinach has been added to the list.

```
import sqlite3 as lite

queryList1 = [("Raspberries",0),("Water",0),("Lemon",1)]
queryList2 = [("Raspberries",1),("Water",0),("Spinach",0)]


# -- open the connection and create a cursor
conn  = lite.connect(':memory:')
cursor = conn.cursor()

conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE shoppingList (
        item STRING UNIQUE,
        checked INTEGER
        );""")

# ----------- First Query -----------------
insertQuery1 = """INSERT INTO shoppingList
            VALUES (:item, :checked);"""
with conn:
    cursor.executemany(insertQuery1, queryList1)


# ----------- Second Query -----------------
insertQuery2 = """INSERT OR IGNORE INTO shoppingList
                 VALUES (:item, :checked);
            """ 
with conn:
    cursor.executemany(insertQuery2, queryList2)

# ----------- Display Result Query -----------------
with conn:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM shoppingLIST")
print(cursor.fetchall())


# ------------------- close the curser and the database ----------------------
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

This code gives me the result:

```
[("Raspberries",0),("Water",0), ("Lemon",1),("Spinach",1)]
```

And it should give me the following result:

```
[("Raspberries",1),("Water",0), ("Lemon",1),("Spinach",1)]
```

I tried updating the database using the following second query command:

```
with conn:
     cursor.executemany("""INSERT OR REPLACE INTO shoppingList VALUES(?,?)
                SELECT item,checked WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM shoppingList
                WHERE checked = 1);
                """, queryList2)
```

This results in a non explained syntax error I cannot resolve.
Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(Raspberries, 0) is the expected result. The second insert is IGNORE'd (Unique constraint violated), no DML is performed. If the sqlite version (`sqlite3.sqlite_version`) is at least 3.24, then perhaps [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) will solve the problem. Or is it simply a typo?

The second query is not valid sqlite3 syntax, full stop. The `SELECT item,checked` phrase has no `from` clause, for starters.